# Get an event when a ListView item is visible or not

Tags: android, listview

I was wondering if there is some kind of OnVisibilyChangeListener for views in a ListView because i would like to have a method called every time a ListView item change its visibility.

I know about the OnPreDrawListener to check if the view is gonna be visible. But how can i check if the view gets scrolled out of the visible screen area?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can implement `OnScrollListener` for ListView and override [`onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScroll%28android.widget.AbsListView,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) and [`onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html#onScrollStateChanged%28android.widget.AbsListView,%20int%29) and get the ListView item that is visible.

`onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)` is the method that will help you to know which row of ListView is visible by using value of `firstVisibleItem` and `visibleItemCount`.

Comment: this works but is there an easy way to determine if the view is 100% visible?, the first and last visible items work even if 1px row of the item is visible in the screen and most of the item is hidden, is there a way to tell if a particular item is 100% on screen?