# Updating specific ListView items when resuming activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have 3 activities containing listviews with custom adapters, an item selected at the first one drives the user to the second one, and so on...

At these listviews, some items are highlighted as "new itens" (each time adapter's getView is called, I check at a database if the current item should be highlighted). Once user has reached the 3rd listview, I mark these items as "checked", and want to propagate this change back to the other listviews...

That means, when user comes back, pulling the 2nd and 1st listviews up from the stack, I want the viewed items not to be highlighted anymore.

I've tried [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19710944/1366650), without success. When executing notifyDataSetChanged() from onResume(), my listview simply didn't shows up. And I'd prefer not to use startActivityforResult()...

here's my code to refresh the listview at onResume():

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    //I have basically the same code at onCreate()
    adapter = new ListingsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), this);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

here's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17963907/1366650) that sounds promising, but I wasn't sure how can I retrieve an specific view from the adapter... I want to check all visible items with adapter.getView(), but it asks for a convertView and a parent ViewGroup and I couldn't get that

Thanks in advance for any hint on this

Answer (score 1):

1. Why don't you wanna use `startActivityforResult()`?
2. You don't need to create  a new adapter every time in `onResume()`. You only need to change the underlying data (set the checked flag for the visited item) and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. This will trigger the adapters `getView()` method for all the visible list elements.

Comment: 1- Is it a problem if I start the 3rd listview directly (for instance with a push notification), and then call `setResult()` without starting this activity with `startActivityForResult()`?

2- You're right! I've realized my problem is another thing: I'm setting items as "viewed" at the `onDestroy` or `onStop` methods at the closing activity, that are called after the  onResume method of the activity that's coming back. Therefore I'm refreshing the listview before updating my database...